# Application class's onCreate initialize firebase.auth error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
public class ApplicationMy extends Application {
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }
}
```

And, I also added option of manifests like below

```
<application
    android:name=".ApplicationMy"
    ...
>
...
</application>
```

In this case above, app is not dead and looks working well, but error-window occurs...

Like Above case, If i do the code like below, It works well perfectly not showing error window.

```
public class ApplicationMy extends Application {
    private int test;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.test = 123;
    }
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: You should post the stackstrace you find with logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume doing that in application class is not the right way. Doing same in an activity wouldn't be a problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }
}
```

This is what I would ask you to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call Firebase.setAndroidContext(Context context) before any other call. Try the following:

```
public class ApplicationMy extends Application {
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        this.firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: In Activities, if I use firebaseAuth instance generated with ApplcationMy, should i call setAndroidContext each time?

Comment: In the Firebase guide, 'In the new SDK, it's no longer necessary to call Firebase.setAndroidContext() so you can remove it from your code.'. [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android)

Comment: I solved the problem. FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)